# FlowType annotating function return type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I need to annotate in FlowType a function which return an object, I see I have several options:

A) Annotation on object exported and function

```
const getForecastHourly:ActionType = (query:number):ActionType => ...
```

B) Annotation on function only:

```
const getForecastHourly = (query:number):ActionType => ...
```

C) Annotation on object exported only:

```
const getForecastHourly:ActionType  = (query:number) => ...
```

In my code I am using version A), but I would like to know if B or C could be equivalent and which version is suggestible and why.

```js
// @flow
import {ActionType} from '../../types'

import 'isomorphic-fetch'
import * as api from '../../app/api'
import * as types from './forecastHourlyActionTypes'

const getForecastHourly:ActionType = (query:number):ActionType => ({
  type: types.GET_FORECAST_HOURLY,
  payload: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(api.forecast(query)).then(response => {
      resolve(response.json())
    })
  })
})

const setForecastHourlyActiveReportType:ActionType = (type:string):ActionType => ({
  type: types.SET_FORECAST_HOURLY_ACTIVE_REPORT_TYPE,
  payload: type
})

export { getForecastHourly, setForecastHourlyActiveReportType }
```

```js
export type ActionType ={
  +type:string,
  +payload: Object
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do is only annotate the function itself like

```js
const getForecastHourly = (query: number): ActionType => ({ /* - */ });
```

Because `flow` knows about `const`, it know the value can't change and will figure the type out itself.

On the other hand if you'd use a `let`, then I'd annotate the variable itself also, so `flow` can check on reassigning the value if it has the correct type.